# Fancybox 2 Extra views of last image in gallery

Tags: fancybox, gallery, fancybox-2

I have a gallery with 8 images using button-helper that works in the html editor going back to the first after the last shows. Uploaded to my website, the same gallery reports 10 images, 8, 9, and 10 are the same final image. This is annoying, not critical.

Comment: it will very difficult to help without any code or a link to your site with the issue.

Comment: Sorry, off on another project last couple of months.